# Why sec:authentication="name" show all user information?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, authentication, thymeleaf

I use Spring Boot, Spring Boot Security, thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5. I want get information about current user and write:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"> 
 Authenticated as <span sec:authentication="name"></span></div>
```

and get All User information Like that:

> Authenticated as User(id=7, firstName=TOGRUL, lastName=Mamedov,
> patronymic=dddddd, email=master555@gmail.com, phone=+99477777777,
> password=$2a$11$txs/zdaLq.6eeBHz3uyM0e/R6uzJHs2.UIeIeRrV906y6Ia/hMOE6,
> enabled=true, secret=MVNSUPKHWTAVLIEQ, country=Azerbaijan, state=Baki,
> city=Badamdar, gender=Man, addressLine=GANJA, zipCode=2001,
> birthDay=01-07-2020, passportSeria=AZE, passportNumber=1234567,
> finCode=1234567, avatar=/resources/images/user-icon.png, mytext=null,
> active=0, isUsing2FA=false, roles=[Role [name=ROLE_USER][id=5]])

For base authentication I use this project.
https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration

How to fix this error if it is a bug? I think password should't be shown anyway.
How get username?
How get other information if it possible? It is look like Array or some.property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are using thymeleaf. Try this expression and instead of "getSomeProperty()" call any get method of your user class

```
${#authentication.getPrincipal().getSomeProperty()}
```

Comment: This code is working th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getFirstName()}" .

Answer (score 0):

[Thymeleaf Extras for Spring Security page on github](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity) explains somewhat more coherently, what `sec:authentication` tag attribute is supposed to convey - in short, e.g. `<div sec:authentication="name"></div>` is supposed to have the same meaning as `<div th:text="${#authentication.name}"></div>`, that is, they will both show the result of calling `getName()` on the `Authentication` object, that can be passed to a controller method automatically when using the Spring Security / Spring MVC framework, and inspected there.

Possibly, the OP was using a custom `UserDetailsService`, constructing his own `User` object, using some kind of `toString()` method for the username in the standard `User(..)` constructor - thus resulting in the above strange display. The `User` object returned from `UserDetailsService` seems to also be returned by `getPrincipal()` method of the `Authentication` object.

In any case, using `${#authentication}` object properties as in the other answer, is a more fine-grained approach to getting all kinds of information for the logged-in user, not just the name (which can be rather ambiguous, as this question testifies)